# Get value in other cell in same row when if condition in for loop is met

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing

I would like to loop through a dataframe column and when a specific value is reached, I would like to save the value in another column I created and called "index" in the same row. Here is an example df:

```
index  value
  0      a
  2      b
  3      c
  9      a
  23     d
```

i trying to code it like this:

```
for value in df["value"]:
    if value == "a":
       current_index = #get value in "index" in current row
```

I cannot simply save all indices of rows where the value is "a" because the rest of my code wouldn't work then.

I think this should be pretty easy but somehow I cannot find the solution.

Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try via boolean masking and loc accessor:

```
out=df.loc[df['value'].eq('a'),'index'].tolist()
```

output of `out`:

```
[0, 9]
```

OR

If you want to create a column then:

```
df['newcol']=df['index'].where(df['value'].eq('a'))
```

output of `df`:

```
    index   value   newcol
0   0       a       0.0
1   2       b       NaN
2   3       c       NaN
3   9       a       9.0
4   23      d       NaN
```